# TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation in views - Django

Tags: django, django-views

i am trying to create register in views but i got this error

TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation in views - Django

error at line 32

```
if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
```

views.py :

```
def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserAccountForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid(): # line 32
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'app_image' in request.FILES:
                profile.app_image = request.FILES['app_image']
            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.error)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserAccountForm()

    return render(requset,'user/regiseter.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered})
```

how i can fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Django but Python error, mixing Tabs and Spaces is not allowed in Python. You should be using either one of those and preferred indentation standard is Spaces of width 4 for each block.

Fix is pretty obvious, replace the Tabs with 4 space characters instead. You should try to configure your IDE/Editor to put 4 spaces whenever Tab is pressed and that should prevent any future occurrences of this.

Please read [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id18) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, I deleted all the spaces and wrote new spaces with the ruler and it worked